# Required is not working on array of input in HTML5

Tags: html

I want to make several text fields required with attribute `required`, but it is not working.

Any idea why? Is it mandatory to do it with JQuery or is there any HTML5 way to do it?

```
<form method="POST" action="https://my.kendozone.com/tournaments/testlt/users" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-horizontal" novalidate="novalidate">

<input type="text" name="firstnames[]" class="form-control" required>
<input type="text" name="firstnames[]" class="form-control" required>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>  
        </form>
```

Here is the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/xoco70/ezt61gw6/2/

Comment: it should just be `required`, not `required=""`. Take a look [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp)

Comment: sorry, my mistake, it is just required, I will correct it

Comment: np, is it still not working?

Comment: no, this is how I have it in my code, I pasted it badly

Comment: the page also says the attribute is not supported in safari, are you using safari?

Comment: nop, I use chrome

Comment: in which browser are you running the application?

Comment: I use chrome 58

Comment: I think you should add submit button in code

Comment: yep, I agree, see jsfiddle

Comment: I get it, in my form tag, I have novalidate="novalidate" :( Sorry for bothering

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this HTML5 **Markup**

```
 <input type="text" name="firstnames[]" class="form-control" required>
 <input type="text" name="firstnames[]" class="form-control" required>
```

Comment: what's the difference?